# Change the text in a listview base adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, radix

I have a custom baseadapter  that i use to populate a listview.  each row that populates contains 4 text views in it. How can I change the text of one of these views without having to repopulate a brand new array into the adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the value into the array and call this method

```
youradapter.notifydatasetchanged()
```